# iOS 8 SDK, Swift, MapKit Drawing a Route

Tags: swift, mapkit, ios8, mkoverlay, mkpolyline

I need to draw route between two points and I'm using `MKDirectionsRequest` for my purpose.

Getting a route is OK, but I have trouble with drawing it.

In iOS 8 SDK there's no function

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
```

There is only this one:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer!
```

And for some reason, I can't understand why that method isn't called.
Delegate for MapView is set and MapKit is imported.

Here is the `rendererForOverlay` function that is implemented:

```
func rendererForOverlay(overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    println("rendererForOverlay");

    var overlayRenderer : MKOverlayRenderer = MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay);

    var overlayView : MKPolylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay);
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5);

    return overlayView;
}
```

Comment: On SO, it's better practice to include at least some of the relevant code in the question itself rather than just a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map view isn't calling your `rendererForOverlay` method because it is not named correctly.

The method must be named exactly:

```
mapView(mapView:rendererForOverlay)
```

but in your code it's named:

```
rendererForOverlay(overlay:)
```

In addition, you should check that the type of the `overlay` argument is `MKPolyline` and set the `strokeColor` of the polyline renderer.

(The `view.backgroundColor` in the existing code is actually changing the background color of the view controller's `view` -- not the polyline.)

Example:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    println("rendererForOverlay");

    if (overlay is MKPolyline) {
        var pr = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay);
        pr.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5);
        pr.lineWidth = 5;
        return pr;
    }

    return nil
}
```