# How to show the direction between two locations on a map in Swift?

Tags: swift, mapkit, direction

I am trying to show the direction between two locations in Swift. When my app launches, first it shows the current location and then I can see the city which I want on the map using a text field and a button. Now I am trying to show directions between current location and searched city.

Thanks to this function, I can see the city which I want on the map:

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

    let addressString = myTextField.text

    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(addressString, completionHandler:
        {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in

            if error != nil
            {
                println("Geocode failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

            else if placemarks.count > 0
            {
                let placemark = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                let location = placemark.location

                self.mapControl(location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
            }
    })
}
```

This is my `mapControl` function which loads the city on the map:

```
func mapControl(latitude : Double, longitude : Double)
{
    var lastlocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(3, 3)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: lastlocation, span: span)
    let regionRadius : CLLocationDistance = 1000
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

How can I show the direction between current location and searched city?

Comment: Do you mean drawing the road driving directions?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723490/display-route-on-map-in-swift and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542085/ios-8-sdk-swift-mapkit-drawing-a-route.  Or do you mean showing the heading from user location to searched city as an arrow?

Comment: yes, i mean drawing the road driving directioins. thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get directions, you actually have to fetch the route from Apple's maps' server using **calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler.**

First create the relevant MKMapItems for both the source and destination, e.g

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
let location = CLLocation(latitude: sourceLatitude, longitude: sourceLongitude)

geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {
    (placemarks:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if placemarks?.count > 0 {
        if let placemark: MKPlacemark = placemarks![0] as? MKPlacemark {
            self.source =  MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        }
    }
    })
```

You also want to repeat this for the destination

```
let request:MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()

// source and destination are the relevant MKMapItems
request.setSource(source)
request.setDestination(destination)

// Specify the transportation type
request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Automobile;

// If you're open to getting more than one route, 
// requestsAlternateRoutes = true; else requestsAlternateRoutes = false;
request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler ({
(response: MKDirectionsResponse?, error: NSError?) in

    if error == nil {
    self.directionsResponse = response
    // Get whichever currentRoute you'd like, ex. 0
    self.route = directionsResponse.routes[currentRoute] as MKRoute
}
})
```

Then after retrieving the **MKRoute**, you can add the polyline to the map like so:

```
mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: MKOverlayLevel.AboveRoads)
```

Doing this you will be able to show the direction between two locations in Swift. Just edit the code, accordingly.